# Invalid regular expression (invalid group)

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error:

```
"message": "Invalid regular expression: /^(?<basename>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\\?(?<testVersion>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(@(?<rawTimestamp>[^.]+))?\\.json/: Invalid group"
```

What's wrong with my regular expression?

```
const FILENAME_ACCEPTOR = /^(?<basename>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\?(?<testVersion>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(@(?<rawTimestamp>[^.]+))?\.json/;
```

Comment: The version of regex you are using probably doesn't support named groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named capture groups (introduced in 2018) are a pretty new thing. The engine you're running on must not support them. Use ordinary numeric capture groups instead, and extract them out into an object later, if that's what you need:

```
const FILENAME_ACCEPTOR = /^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(@([^.]+))?\.json/;
```

Here, the first capturing group (`[1]`) will correspond to the `basename`, the third `[3]` will correspond to the `testVersion`, and the fourth `[4]` will correspond to the `rawTimestamp`. (Your original regex already has a capture group, which comes between the 1st and 3rd named groups - if you aren't actually using it, probably best to remove it)